# Absolute positioning – advaned

Tags: jquery, positioning

I’ve got a div (the white arrow at the bottom center) which should stick at the bottom of the browser window when the big responsive image protrudes beyond the viewport at the bottom (wide view), but the arrow’s lowest position should be the bottom end of the image (narrow view).

My problem is:
When the browser window is wider the position of the arrow, which currently always sticks at the bottom of the window, is fine, but when the window becomes smaller the lowest position should be the bottom end of the image and not the at the bottom of the window.

**Here’s a fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/A4Xd6/

**HTML**

```
<div class="scroll-down"><a href="#content"></a></div>


<div class="rslides_container">

    <ul class="rslides">
        <li><img src="http://chrismagiera.de/dev/img/IMG_20140125_121738.jpg" /></li>
    </ul>

</div>


<section id="subsite" role="main">

    <div class="span2" id="content">

        <p>This is some content.</p>

    </div>

    <div class="span2">

        <p>This is some content.</p>

    </div>


</section>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    background: #e2e2e2;
}

section {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1020px;
}

.span2 {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px;
    width: 490px;
}

.scroll-down,
.scroll-down a {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 65px;
}

.scroll-down {
    bottom: -25px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -25px;
    z-index: 1000;
    background: url('http://chrismagiera.de/dev/img/arrow-down.svg') no-repeat;
}

.rslides_container {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

.rslides {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: left;    
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.rslides li {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.rslides img {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($(this).scrollTop()>0){
        $('.scroll-down').fadeOut(800);
    }
    else {
        $('.scroll-down').fadeIn();
    }
});

$('.scroll-down a').on('click', function(event){     
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}, 600);
});
```

**Live:**
http://chrismagiera.de/dev/

**Screenshot with some notes:**
http://chrismagiera.de/dev/position-div.jpg

Hope some of you guys could help out!

Comment: like this [http://jsfiddle.net/A4Xd6/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/A4Xd6/1/)?

Comment: See the live site for more clarity. The fiddle is just for the code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the scroll-down inside the div container of the image. The div container of the image must have position relative, and the arrow position must be absolute. (They already are) Then the position will be related with the height of the image container and not the window. And I think you must to listen events load and resize. When the window is resized you must calculate where must be the arrow. Or other way is to let your code and change only the position of the arrow. Inside the container or outside.

```
<div class="rslides_container">

    <ul class="rslides" id="slider4">
        <li><img src="http://chrismagiera.de/dev/img/IMG_20140125_121738.jpg" /></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="scroll-down"><a href="#content"></a></div>
</div>

<script>
var repositionArrow = function () {
    var slider_height = $(".rslides_container").height();
    var window_height = $(window).height();
    if(window_height < slider_height) {
        $(".scroll-down").css("bottom",(slider_height-window_height)+"px");
        $(".scroll-down").css("top", "inherit");
    }
    else {
        $(".scroll-down").css("bottom", "inherit");
        $(".scroll-down").css("top", slider_height+"px");

    }
};

$(window).load(function() {   
    repositionArrow();    
});
$(window).resize(function() {   

    repositionArrow();
});
</script>
```

**Solution:** http://jsfiddle.net/A4Xd6/6/ -> An example calculating the position relative to the window and image

Comment: Thanks — but no, I want the arrow always visible. Now it’s not visible when the image is higher than the viewport. In that case it should stick to the bottom of the window not to the bottom of the image.

Comment: yes I noticed that, I have another result but I have to test it. Sorry

Comment: Thanks for your effort!

Comment: ^^ I think http://jsfiddle.net/A4Xd6/6/ is what you need. I hope everything is ok

Answer (score 0):

Just check the window height against the element height.

### Fixed Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/A4Xd6/2/ or http://jsfiddle.net/A4Xd6/4/

```
var i = $(".slide");
if(i.height() < $(this).height()) { }
```

Comment: @user1706680 You're welcome. Make sure to mark the correct answer.